# How can one set javadoc options in a wrapper of the standard doclet?

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet, umlgraph

The [UMLGraph](http://umlgraph.org/) doclet [UmlGraphDoc](https://github.com/dspinellis/UMLGraph/blob/master/src/main/java/org/umlgraph/doclet/UmlGraphDoc.java) first runs the standard Java doclet with code like the following:

```
public static boolean start(RootDoc root) {
    com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(root);
```

and then modifies the result to add UML class diagrams.

The UMLGraph doclets introduce a number of custom tags, such as `@depend` and `@has`.  Custom tags can be specified using the [Taglet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) interface and passed to javadoc with the `-taglet` and `-tagletpath` options.  My question is: how can these options can be specified to the standard doclet when it is invoked from another doclet?

Here are some things I have explored:

- The javadoc [Taglet manager](http://www.outerthoughts.com/files/doclet-javadoc/com/sun/tools/doclets/internal/toolkit/taglets/TagletManager.html) offers an `addCustomTag` method, but this is not a public API.
- Implementing the `com.sun.tools.doclets.Configuration` class could allow the specification of options.  There are hints in  [an old implementation I've found](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/1.3/tooldocs/javadoc/source/Configuration.java) that this could work, but this, again, does not seem to be part of the javadoc public API.
- [Subclassing (rather than calling) the standard doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html#custom).  The provided documentation is outdated and contains dead links. Not very reassuring.
- [Running the standard doclet programmatically](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html#runningprogrammatically), rather than extending it from another doclet.  It is not clear how this can work from another doclet.